# Getting decimal value of result

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, logarithm

How can I get the decimal value of any result? I have looked at [Output Format for Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OutputFormatsForNumbers.html), and think that the N function should do the trick, but I can't work it out. For instance:

```
In[1]:=  N[Ln[2], 4]
Out[2]:= Ln[2.000]
```

Obviously I want the evaluation of Ln[2] as a decimal, i.e. 0.6931....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `Ln[]` in Mathematica. `Log[]` is, by default, *natural* log.

Go with:

```
N[Log[2], 4]
```

or (cleaner, imho):

```
Log[2] // N
```

Comment: Also, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com is another place where you can ask this kind of question.